# Disable spring processing of @Named

Tags: spring, jsf-2.2

Is there a possibility to configure spring so that it doesn't initialize beans with @Named annotations?

My current work around is to make such beans @Lazy so they don't get initialized when the application context is created, but I would prefer to have nothing related to spring in such classes.

Note this two options are not good for me:
1. Suggesting to go back to a previous version of spring that didn't support JSR-299 is not an 
2. Putting JSF beans in a package that is not auto-scanned by spring.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you using the `@Named` annotation without wanting the beans to be added to the `ApplicationContext`?

Comment: I want to use Spring for my services layer only, while using standard JSF and CDI for the presentation layer.

Comment: As far as I can tell, axtavt's answer appears to be the best.  The `ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider` class is what is looking for the `Named` annotation that you are utilizing, and following it up, there seems like no trivial way to prevent it from being added to the `includeFitlers` field.  When the `ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner`  looks at the include/exclude filters, it processes the excludes first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to exclude `@Named` using a filter when configuring component scanning (in `<context:component-scan>` or `@ComponentScan`).

**See also:**

- [4.10.3 Using filters to customize scanning](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-scanning-filters)